# Updated Datastore without using Key#id by using java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have the sample code below which updates the records based on the key id but i need a sample script which updates the DS values based on other columns rather than using key i also tried using query but couldn't find a solution.

```
 boolean markDone(long id) {
    Transaction transaction = datastore.newTransaction();
    try {
      Entity task = transaction.get(keyFactory.newKey(id));
      if (task != null) {
        transaction.put(Entity.newBuilder(task).set("done", true).build());
      }
      transaction.commit();
      return task != null;
    } finally {
      if (transaction.isActive()) {
        transaction.rollback();
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[This page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries) has a number of query examples.

If you want the query to be part of a transaction, it will need to be an ancestor query.

Comment: Thank you! @ Ed Davisson